# Why are the children disappointed to see that Dory is alive?

Tags: plot-explanation, finding-dory

Toward the beginning of *Finding Dory*, Dory acts as an assistant to Mr. Ray to help teach the children about migration. Later in this scene, Dory has an accident which renders her briefly unconscious. When one child asks if Dory is dead, Mr. Ray informs him that she is alive and the children appear to groan in disappointment.

[image]

**Is there anything in the movie or in other works that explains why the children are disappointed to discover that Dory is not dead?** The movie indicates that Dory's short-term memory loss can be an annoyance at times, but the children (especially Nemo) appear to have a good relationship with her so it seems odd to me that the children would be noticeably disappointed to find that she was not killed.

Comment: Wanting their teacher dead is completely reasonable!

Comment: Kids! *Whatyagonnado?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Simply put, no.

There is no deliberate explanation for the children's disappointment, but I think it's fair to say that it is just kids being kids:

- As brought up by *madmada*, it is not unusual for a kid to want their teacher dead.
- Kids are also known to be particularly curious, and it is not unreasonable to assume they would delight in the opportunity to see a dead body; after all, it would not be something they would have seen, before.
- Being kids, they would not be expected to weigh up the ramifications of Dory actually being dead (I.e. only seeing the good side, neglecting the bad side, outright).
- Lastly, and I personally believe this to be the absolute reasoning; Finding Dory is a movie *for kids*. Yes, a lot of grown ups watch it, but it is a movie targeted at children. It doesn't have to make sense, if it gets a laugh or two. I certainly chuckled.

Comment: "The good side" - being an exiting, noteworthy event that they witnessed first hand and could tell stories about, with themselves being somewhat prominent in those stories. You mentioned a good side, but I think a natural question would be "what would be considered good about a dead fish?", which you never actually touched on.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, a; seeing something they have not seen, before. b; the teachers dead (yay - less schoolwork). Touched on both. Don't see any other 'good sides'.

Comment: I was just noting that the Dory-specific one seemed more implied, so I figured some might feel something was missing. I like the answer just fine.